# Is it safe to subscribe to an observable with an async function

Tags: typescript, async-await, rxjs

I have an event emitter that sends events at 50Hz.
I'd like to subscribe to this emitter with an async method. The code looks like the following:

```
this.emitter = fromEventPattern(this.addHandler, this.removeHandler, (err, char) => [err, char]);
this.rxSubscription = this.emitter.subscribe(this.handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor);
```

and

```
       handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor = async (arr: any[]): Promise<void> => {
   ...
   await someMethodAsync();
   ...
}
```

I maybe wrong but I'm under the impression that awaiting in there makes the emitter calls onNext() immediately because I've exited the method.

This is very difficult to debug with console calls because of the event rate.

Am I right or wrong?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT 1**:

I'm using typescript targetting ES2015 so a state machine is generated for async/await.

If I'm right, how can I ensure that calls do not overlap? I need to compute averages on values I receive.

Comment: Improved the sample and added more information.

Comment: use `concatMap(value => asyncFunction(value))` for that

Comment: @Kos If I understand you correctly, I have to move my async call away from subscribe? I can't seem to be able to use concatMap on my emitter. this.emitter.concatMap(value:any => this.handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor(value)).subscribe(); won't compile.

Comment: Generally, you should limit `.subscribe()` to simple data consuming. If you have something async that should be part of your stream — then put it into the `.pipe`. Regarding your usage: ensure you got all the syntax right and that your method returns a promise or another observable. Heres a playground for a [concatMap with a promise](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/201babaf39591ca11c00d9224e78efd0). If you'll have further questions — please feel free to open another question with your usecase. GL

Comment: @Kos I just [did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835700/how-to-make-an-rxjs-subscription-with-an-async-function-serialize-the-onnext-cal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> awaiting in there makes the emitter calls onNext() immediately because I've exited the method

You are correct. Rx ignores the return types of its subscription functions, so it ignores the promise returned from your `async` function when it hits its first `await`. This means:

1. As soon as another item arrives on the observable, Rx will invoke your subscription function again. It ignored the promise that was returned, so it doesn't know the old invocation is still in progress.
2. Exceptions from your `async` function will be ignored, since the promise was ignored. Some promise libraries have a global "unobserved promise error" event that can handle this.

Comment: I've edited my question to add a complementaray question.

Comment: I suggest asking another question. I don't know enough about Rx.JS to answer the new question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what your concerns are.  It is valid, your method will be called once for each and every element.  It isn't going to skip anything or cut your method off halfway through but:

1. It will not wait for one iteration of `handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor` to finish before starting another (assuming `handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor` truly does something asynchronous) so you could have multiple instances of `handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor` in flight at the same time.
2. Similarly, if you have multiple subscribers then it will not wait for `handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor` to finish before sending the event to the next subscriber.